# PHP-MYSQL Get and Print the timestamp twice (DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %r') ) in different formats (one with hour, one without)

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, date-format

NEVER YOU MIND, I ALREADY SOLVED IT. I JUST USED DATE_FORMAT ... AS ... and, problem solved.

I have this code. I have a field that gives me the time and the hour automatically (TIMESTAMP), and everything works perfectly, except that in the 'results' not the divider... I need to, also; display the hour, which, you must know, if I add the '%r' for some reason it will separate my tables by 'Hour' and not by 'Month/year' as I want to.

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("starplastdb", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y') date, name, destinatary FROM received ORDER BY date DESC");


$currentDate = false;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
if ($row['date'] != $currentDate){

 echo
  "<table id='llamadas'><tr><td colspan='4'>" .  
  $row['date'] . 
  "</tr></td>" ;
  $currentDate = $row['date'];

  echo "<tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Persona que llama</th>
        <th>Destinatario</th>
    </tr> <tr>";
}

  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['destinatary'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }  

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

What I want to do, is maybe make another query so I can do that or I don't know what solution can you provide, so i can show this:

```
"<table id='llamadas'><tr><td colspan='4'>" .  
      $row['date'] . 
      "</tr></td>" ;
```

in this format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

and here:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
```

in this format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d/%m/%Y %r')
```

Is there a way to do that, be it by PHP or just making two queries in MYSQL directly? I know people says it's very bad to do that, but it's for a very simple app, as you can infer.

Thank you a lot! I'm super stuck!

Comment: What I would suggest you is that, then you are selecting something it's better to select how it is in MySQL and then using PHP adjust it as you want, use the date_format PHP function here is the docs for it http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

Comment: it only allows me to put the current date or a random date. But the row 'date' is automatically generated which is why I'm so confused. Because I cannot put two different format of automatics timestamps